# How to compile multiple files in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala programming and I'm not sure how to compile 4 files at the same time. I know if I have a simple file I can do this from the terminal:

```
scalac program.scala
```

But I have not idea how to do it with multiple files.  How can I run them using Eclipse or Terminal?

Comment: I wrote the following for my students: http://www.dhgarrette.com/nlpclass/scala/setup.html.  It explains how to set up SBT, which makes it easy to compile multi-file projects (including with tests), as well as how to easily get things integrated with Eclipse.

Comment: One remark: SBT does not necessarily need a certain project structure or a build file. If you have just a bunch of files in a directory "sbt run" will compile and run them. This is very nice for small experiments and stuff like that, especially as you can use all the features like incremental compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all your scala files in one directory, you can do this with `scalac *.scala`.

The better way would be to set up some build tool like sbt (see @dhg comment), maven or anything else you are using in other projects.

Comment: Say that I don't wish to use any build tool. Is it at least technically possible to do everything Scala is capable of, without using one?